# Get data from association in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the next associations in Sequelize :

```
db.checktypes.belongsToMany(db.questions, {
  through: db.checktypeslike,
});
db.questions.belongsToMany(db.checktypes, {
  through: db.checktypeslike,
});
```

and

```
db.checktypeslike.hasMany(db.dropdown, { as: 'options' }, { onUpdate: 'cascade' });
db.dropdown.belongsTo(db.checktypeslike);
```

I have tried to get the **dropdown** which is related to **checktypeslike** but I don't know how, because **checktypeslike** is the middle table between **checktypes** and **questions** (MaN),

I use this to make the call :

```
.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: db.questions,
          as: 'questions',
          include: [
            {
              model: checkType,
              as: 'checktypes',
              through: { attributes: ['x', 'x1', 'x2', ] },
            },
```

I have tried to put in **through** an include but doesn't work.
If somebody can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "model: checkType" when every time you have "db.checktypes".
Does your "checktypeslike" table has its own IDs?

Comment: @digitalniweb "model:checkType" is "db.checktypes" but i had defined `const checkType = db.checktypes` , and checktypeslike has its own ID, i utilize that id to associate to another table that is the "db.dropdown".

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `hasMany` to `checktypeslike` in order to get its child association records:

```js
db.checktypes.hasMany(db.checktypeslike, { as: 'checktypeslikes' });
db.checktypeslike.belongsTo(db.questions, { as: 'question' });
```

Now you can get all together:

```js
db.checktypes.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: db.checktypeslike,
      as: 'checktypeslikes',
      include: [{
        model: db.questions,
        as: 'question',
      }, {
        model: db.dropdown,
        as: 'options',
      }]
    }]
 });
```